# Injecting dependency into MVC controller with Spring .NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, spring.net

The object in the controller is not getting injected at run time.

Web.config:

```
    <sectionGroup name="spring">
        <section name="context" type="Spring.Context.Support.ContextHandler, Spring.Core" />
        <section name="objects" type="Spring.Context.Support.DefaultSectionHandler, Spring.Core" />
    </sectionGroup>
```

.
.
.

```
<!-- Spring Context Configuration -->
<spring>
    <context>
        <resource uri="config://spring/objects"/>
    </context>
    <objects configSource="App_Config\Spring.config" />
</spring>
<!-- End Spring Context Configuration -->
```

Spring.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net">

    <!-- Crest is the WCF service to be exposed to the client, could not use a singleton -->

    <object id="TestController" type="Project.Controllers.TestController, Project" singleton="false">
        <property name="ObjectA" ref="ObjectImpl"/>
    </object>

    <object id="ObjectImpl" type="Project.Code.Implementations.ClassA, Project" singleton="false" />

</objects>
```

TestController:

```
public class TestController: Controller
    {
        // this object will be injected by Spring.net at run time
        private ClassA ObjectA { get; set; }
```

Problem:

> At runtime the ObjectA does not get injected and stays null, which
>   cause null exception throughout the code.

Alternative:
I can manually initialize the Spring object and get it's object using the following code.

```
        var ctx = ContextRegistry.GetContext();
        var objectA = ((IObjectFactory)ctx).GetObject("ObjectImpl") as ClassA;
```

Comment: You are missing some pieces of the puzzle. Please have a look on [here](http://foldingair.blogspot.hu/2010/01/springnet-and-aspmvc-getting-started.html) and also [here](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/web-mvc.html) and [here](http://nuget.org/packages/Spring.Web.Mvc/1.3.2).

Comment: @nemesv yes you are correct, it turns out I was missing a piece of the puzzle.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out I was missing a pretty important part of Spring Implementation for MVC.

My solution to the problem was by adding a DependencyResolver which implements the IDependencyResolver.

DependencyResolver:

```
public class SpringDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly IApplicationContext _context;

    public SpringDependencyResolver(IApplicationContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        var dictionary = _context.GetObjectsOfType(serviceType).GetEnumerator();

        dictionary.MoveNext();
        try
        {
            return dictionary.Value;
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
            return _context.GetObjectsOfType(serviceType).Cast<object>();
    }
}
```

Global.asax.cs:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SpringDependencyResolver(ContextRegistry.GetContext()));
    }
```

Comment: This won't work becaus the context is in creation and `ContextRegistry.GetContext()` will throw an exception!

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own `IDependencyResolver`, like you suggest in your answer. Please note however that since (iirc) version 1.3.1 Spring.NET has built-in support for asp.net mvc [2.0](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/web-mvc.html) and [3.0](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/web-mvc3.html). Spring.net 2.0 ([pre release available on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Spring.Web.Mvc4)) has built in support for version 4.0 too. Consider using these libraries instead.

You might be interested in comparing your `SpringDependencyResolver` to the [the one provided by the Spring.net team](https://fisheye.springsource.org/browse/spring-net/src/Spring/Spring.Web.Mvc3/SpringMvcDependencyResolver.cs?hb=true).

Comment: Thanks @Marijn for the advise.  You are correct with the Spring.NET built-in support.  But the problem in our case is that we are using MVC4 framework and Spring.net 2.0 is not yet ready for production release.  So a custom implementation fits better for our situation.  I'll have a look at the DependencyResolver [provided by Spring](https://fisheye.springsource.org/browse/spring-net/src/Spring/Spring.Web.Mvc4/SpringMvcDependencyResolver.cs?hb=true), Thanks!

Comment: I tried to use the Spring-provided dependency resolver but in my Global.asax (method init, inheriting from MvcApplication) "DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SpringDependencyResolver(ContextRegistry.GetContext()));" throws error saying context is still under creation. Any idea on what's wrong in my case?